# Pandas: Filling nan poor performance - avoid iterating over rows?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a performance problem with filling missing values in my dataset. This concerns a 500mb / 5.000.0000 row dataset (Kaggle: Expedia 2013).

It would be easiest to use `df.fillna()`, but it seems I cannot use this to fill every NaN with a different value.

I created a `lookup` table:

```
srch_destination_id | Value
    2        0.0110
    3        0.0000
    5        0.0207
    7           NaN
    8           NaN
    9           NaN
    10       0.1500
    12       0.0114
```

This table contains per `srch_destination_id` the corresponding value to replace `NaN` with in `dataset`.

```
# Iterate over dataset row per row. If missing value (NaN), fill in the min. val
# found in lookuptable.
for row in range(len(dataset)):
    if pd.isnull(dataset.iloc[row]['prop_location_score2']):
        cell = dataset.iloc[row]['srch_destination_id']
        df.set_value(row, 'prop_location_score2', lookuptable.loc[cell])
```

This code works when iterating over 1000 rows, but when iterating over all 5 million rows, my computer never finishes (I waited hours).

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Series.fillna` does accept a series or a dictionary, as well as scalar replacement values.

Therefore, you can create a series mapping from `lookup`:

```
s = lookup.set_index('srch_destination')['Value']
```

Then use this to fill in `NaN` values in `dataset`:

```
dataset['prop_loc'] = dataset['prop_loc'].fillna(dataset['srch_destination'].map(s.get))
```

Notice that in the `fillna` input we are mapping an identifier from `dataset`. In addition, we use `pd.Series.map` to perform the necessary mapping.